# Django form is not showing up on template

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to show two forms (`UserRegisterForm` and `TeacherRegisterForm`) in one template. But, only the `UserRegisterForm` is showing up in the rendered HTML.

**teacher-register.html**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% crispy user_form %}
  {% crispy teacher_form %}
  <div class="form-group mt-3">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('register/', register, name='register'),
    path('TeacherRegister/', register_teacher, name='teacher-register'),
    path('logout/', sign_out, name='logout'),
    path('profile/', sign_out, name='logout'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def register_teacher(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('dashboard')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        teacher_form = TeacherRegisterForm(request.POST,
                                           request.FILES)
        if user_form.is_valid() and teacher_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_student = False
            user.is_teacher = True
            user.save()
            profile = teacher_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile.save()
            messages.success(
                request, f'Your account has been created!')
            return redirect('login')

    else:
        user_form = UserRegisterForm()
        teacher_form = TeacherRegisterForm()

    context = {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'teacher_form': teacher_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'accounts/teacher-register.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class TeacherRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField(
        label='Profile Picture',
        help_text='Upload a recent clear image.',
        required=False,
    )
    birth_date = forms.DateField(
        label='Birth Date',
        widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
    )
    facebook = forms.URLField(
        label='Facebook Profile URL'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = [
            'image',
            'birth_date',
            'facebook',
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Div('image', css_class="col-sm-6"),
                Div('birth_date', css_class="col-sm-6"),
                css_class='row',
            ),
            FloatingField('facebook'),
        )
```

**models.py**

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                primary_key=True)
    image = models.ImageField(
        default='profile_pics/default.jpg', upload_to=location, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    facebook = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course,
                                     related_name='teachers',
                                     blank=True)
    sessions = ChainedManyToManyField(Session,
                                      chained_field='courses',
                                      chained_model_field='course',
                                      related_name='teachers',
                                      blank=True)
    batches = ChainedManyToManyField(Batch,
                                     chained_field='sessions',
                                     chained_model_field='session',
                                     horizontal=True,
                                     related_name='teachers',
                                     blank=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name}'
```

I did the same thing for `student-register.html` template and it's working fine. I've searched for hours but couldn't find any bug in my code.

**EDIT:**

In **views.py**, if I set `teacher_form = StudentRegisterForm()`, the `StudentRegisterForm` appears in the `teacher-register.html` template. So, I guess the problem might be somewhere in the `class TeacherRegisterForm()`

Comment: Have you tried it without Crispy? `{{user_form.as_p}}{{teacher_form.as_p}}`. (I can't see a bug. I like Crispy a lot but it's a level of complexity to remove while bug-hunting! )

Comment: @nigel222 Yes, I've tried it without Crispy. The `user_form` appears with or without Crispy. But the `teacher_form` doesn't.

Comment: Guessing again: try removing the explicit field definitions, and see whether it works right with the ones created by `ModelForm` and the Meta fields declaration. If I'm right, then put back `birth_date` and `facebook`. `ImageField`s are more "different".

Comment: I tried doing that before, but it didn't work. But the good news is, I found the bug. I've posted it as an Answer.

Thank you, @nigel222, for your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow had this code way below in my **forms.py** file:

```
class TeacherRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = []
```

I have no idea where it came from. It was overriding my main `TeacherRegisterForm()` class, which is why no fields were appearing in the template.

Removing it solved the problem.

Comment: Well done. "When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth" Sherlock Holmes - Sir Arthur Conan Doyle